# Trabalhar com duas treeviews e seus itens em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Tenho duas treeviews semelhantes, porém com items diferentes, no caso, uma delas traz um diálogo em português enquanto a outra deveria trazer o mesmo diálogo em inglês. Tenho duas caixas de texto, uma para colocar o texto em inglês outra para colocar o texto em português.

Quando seleciono um item da treeview fico com um `selectedDialogue = tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;` alocado apontando para o item selecionado na arvore em português.

Quando pressiono o botão ADD adiciono um novo item a lista do Diálogo selecionado na arvore de diálogos português com o header deste item contendo o texto da caixa de texto em português.

Até aqui tudo ocorre da maneira certa, aparecem os textos e a arvore em português é carregada, mas no mesmo ponto onde adiciono o texto em português quero buscar o item da treeview em inglês que esteja na mesma posição do dialogo selecionado, não consigo encontrar este índice de forma alguma.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem itemTemp = new TreeViewItem();
        itemTemp.Header = txtLanguagePTDialogue.Text;
        selectedDialogue.Items.Add(itemTemp);

        this.txtLanguagePTDialogue.Text = string.Empty;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtLanguageENDialogue.Text))
        {
            TreeViewItem itemTempEN = new TreeViewItem();
            itemTemp2.Header = txtLanguageENDialogue.Text;

            var itemDialogueEN = trDialoguesEN.Items[selectedDialogue.PersistId] as TreeViewItem;
            itemDialogueEN.Items.Add(itemTempEN);
        }
    }
```

Preciso de ideias, não queria carregar outro treeviewitem apontando para a treeview em inglês. Obrigado a todos.